# log4j 2 RollingFile not rolling over

Tags: java, tomcat7, log4j2

We have WAR deployments running on Tomcat containers which are using `log4j 2.5` for logging events. We have now amended the deployments' log4j2.xml configuration to have the log files roll over every 24 hours but, with this new configuration, the rollover of files are not taking place as we would expect.

Sample configuration:

```
    <RollingFile name="file"
        fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${web:contextPath}.log" 
        filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${web:contextPath}-%d{dd-MMM-yyyy}.log"
        append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" >
            <header>LOG START DATE=${date:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} APP=${web:contextPath} TOMCAT=${env:HOSTNAME}:${env:CONNECTOR_PORT}${sys:line.separator}</header>
            <footer>LOG END DATE=${date:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} APP=${web:contextPath} TOMCAT=${env:HOSTNAME}:${env:CONNECTOR_PORT}${sys:line.separator}</footer>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

Any ideas why the rollover is not taking place?

NOTE: The same configuration but with a `<CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?" />` instead of `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` does rollover but, in this case, the rolled over files get created with today's date in the filename and NOT yesterday's date.

NOTE2: We have other deployments with similar configuration that do rollover every 24 hours but those configurations have the filename hardcoded instead of using `${web:contextPath}`. Could this lookup have something to do with why RollingFile might not work?

--- EDIT ---

UPDATE: We are able to get TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy to rollover files using above configuration when the Tomcat instance is running on Windows but NOT when the Tomcat instance is running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your configuration snippet as I get the desired behaviour of time based rolling.
To test, I changed the `dd-MMM-yyyy` to `dd-MMM-yyyy-HH-mm` and my log file rolls every minute.

It must be something else that is preventing you from achieving the desired behaviour.

My setup #1:

- Log4j2 v2.8.2
- Apache Tomcat 8.5.13
- Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

My setup #2:

- Log4j2 v2.5
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.77
- CentOS 7 (1611)

I have the following 3 JARs in WEB-INF/lib:

- log4j-api-2.5.jar
- log4j-core-2.5.jar
- log4j-web-2.5.jar

Here is my complete log4j2.xml for your reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender"
            fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${web:contextPath}.log" 
            filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${web:contextPath}-%d{dd-MMM-yyyy-HH-mm}.log"
            append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" >
                <header>LOG START DATE=${date:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} APP=${web:contextPath} TOMCAT=${env:HOSTNAME}:${env:CONNECTOR_PORT}${sys:line.separator}</header>
                <footer>LOG END DATE=${date:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} APP=${web:contextPath} TOMCAT=${env:HOSTNAME}:${env:CONNECTOR_PORT}${sys:line.separator}</footer>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: At our end we are currently forced to use `log4j2 v2.5` jars. I've run a deployment on a Windows hosted Tomcat and on windows the rollover worked fine just like in your setup. But not when the Tomcat is running on Linux. I've checked all jar versions both inside WAR and in Tomcat libs and I am pretty sure all jar versions match between Linux and Windows setups. The only way I can get rollover to work on Linux so far is using `CronTriggeringPolicy` instead and I have set the trigger to `"0 59 23 * * ?"` to ensure rollover file date is of the day before.

Comment: I have just updated my answer as I have successfully tested on Linux also. Which Linux are you using?